# ASP.NET Core - Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Models.Student>' to 'Domain.Models.Student'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dapper

In my ASP.NET Core-7 Web API project, I am implementing Dapper to fetch list of all students and display the record.
I have the code as shown below:

**Response:**

```
public class Response<T>
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }

    public Response(int statusCode, bool success, string msg, T data)
    {
        Data = data;
        Successful = success;
        StatusCode = statusCode;
        Message = msg;
    }
    public Response()
    {
    }

    public static Response<T> Success(string successMessage, T data, int statusCode = 200)
    {
        return new Response<T> { Successful = true, Message = successMessage, Data = data, StatusCode = statusCode };
    }
    public override string ToString() => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
}
```

Then the model is as shown below:

**Model:**

```
public class Student
{
    public string RegCode { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
}
```

Service:

```
public async Task<Response<IEnumerable<Student>>> GetAllStudentsListAsync()
{
    var response = new Response<Student>();
    using IDbConnection dbConnection = Connection;
    try
    {
        string sQuery = @"SELECT * FROM students";
        dbConnection.Open();
        var listaSql = await dbConnection.QueryAsync<Student>(sQuery);
        response.Data = listaSql;
        response.Message = $"Successfully Retrieved Students List";
        response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
        response.Successful = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.Error($"An Error occured " + ex.Message); 
        response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        response.Successful = false;
        response.Message = $"Student Record Retrieval Failed. Please try again";
        return response;
    }
    finally
    {
        dbConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

Finally I have this:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult<Response<IEnumerable<Student>>> GetAllStudentsListAsync()
{
    var result = _studentService.GetAllStudentsListAsync();
    return result;
}
```

But I got this error:

Error   CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Models.Student>' to 'Domain.Models.Student'

How do I get this resolve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this line:

```
var response = new Response<Student>();
```

Second line of `GetAllStudentsListAsync`. you defined `Response<Student>` so `Data` turns to `Student` not `IEnumerable<Student>` so you got an error because of it.

Replace it with:

```
var response = new Response<IEnumerable<Student>>();
```

Solves the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Please read Stack Overflow guides and improve your question. For starters, what code does the exception apply to?

Second, the error is self-explanatory. Somewhere, you retrieve a list of students and try to assign to a variable that is Student. List ==> Student doesn't work.

If I were to guess *where* it happens, this code looks very suspicious:

```
string sQuery = @"SELECT * FROM students";
var listaSql = await dbConnection.QueryAsync<Student>(sQuery);
```

Probably should be `var listaSql = await dbConnection.QueryAsync<List<Student>>(sQuery);` instead

Comment: As in the answer from @RezaNoei the problem is in the declaration of `response`, not the Dapper query,